# Upgrade Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, iso

I want to upgrade Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 with a USB bootable of Ubuntu 16.04 but at "Installation type" step I cann't choose "Upgrade Ubunutu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.4".
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't upgrade using that method. Instead boot your normal system and run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
reboot
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You may need to run on a server `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`.